# NotFoundHttpException named route PHP Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, named-routing

```
Route::get('user/profile', function () {
return 'test' })->name('profile');
```

But I always get error when I call the address/profile
if i use address/user/profile it works just fine.

The error list shown in my browser :

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Where do I miss ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: To get address/profile your route needs to be Route::get('profile')....

Going to address/user/profile is the exact route you have defined thats why that one will work

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out. I just bought a new laravel book and I thought we can call the alias we make using name() as the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change route from `user/profile` to `profile`

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
   return 'test' })->name('profile');
```

`name()` only create alias name for route not changing the URL

Comment: then , what should I do so I can call the URL as the name of the alias ?

Comment: ooh I see..
I just figured it out just right now. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('user/profile', function () {
return 'test'; })->name('profile');
```

Try This.Hope It will work!!

Comment: Then I don't know how to do it.